# How do I retrieve pdf files stored in Hadoop HDFS from a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, web, filesystems, storage

I am currently building a search engine for pdfs. I am using elastic search to ingest the the pdf data. As it has been advised by most people not to store binary files in elastic, it was suggested I store the files in Hadoop HDFS. However, how do I retrieve the the actual files stored HDFS from my webapp. Is there an API? Or simply adding a link to the pdf should retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [WebHDFS API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)